# How to execute a Windows command on a remote PC?

Tags: windows, cmd

Is it possible to execute a Windows shell command on a remote PC when I know its login name and password? 
Is it possible to do it using client PC's Windows shell?

Answer (score 57):

If you are in a domain environment, you can also use:

```
winrs -r:PCNAME cmd
```

This will open a remote command shell.

Comment: This runs much faster than psexec

Comment: faster and no need to install anything

Comment: One downside --- and probably the reason it's faster -- is that you have to set up the remote computer in advance to accept requests.

Comment: It is very handy, and if you are inside a domain environment, as stated in the response, there is no need for additional setup.

Comment: As jpaugh stated you have to setup the machines in advance.  By default Windows Remote Management is set to manual.  Luckily there are commands to also start that service manually if need be.

Comment: (Spanish error) "Winrs error:El cliente WinRM no puede procesar la solicitud. La autenticación CredSSP está deshabilitada en la configuración del cliente. (...). La autenticación CredSSP también debe estar habilitada en la configuración del servidor. Además, debe editarse la directiva de grupo para permitir la delegación de credenciales en el equipo de destino. Use gpedit.msc y mire en la siguiente directiva: Configuración del equipo -> Plantillas administrativas -> Sistema -> Delegación de credenciales -> Permitir delegación de credenciales nuevas.  (...)"

Answer (score 39):

```
psexec \\RemoteComputer cmd.exe
```

or use ssh or TeamViewer or RemoteDesktop!

Comment: 'psexec' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @bubble psexec is from Windows Sysinternals: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Hey bro, when i execute this it just freezes for me... It freezes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19):

This can be done by using `PsExec` which can be downloaded [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)

```
psexec \\computer_name -u username -p password ipconfig
```

If this isn't working try doing this :-

1. Open RegEdit on your remote server.
2. Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System.
3. Add a new DWORD value called LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy
4. Set its
   value to 1.
5. Reboot your remote server.
6. Try running PSExec again from
   your local server.

Comment: psexec wouldn't work for me until I added the registry key as you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: @jippyjoe4 No worries. If this helped you please upvote the answer. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Tested on Windows 10 x64 build 10.0.19041. In my case, I set up both computers so they were on the same subnet: using Adapter Settings for IPv4, set one PC to 192.168.1.2, the other to 192.168.1.3, both with subnet 255.255.255.0, then edited registry on remote PC, rebooted remote, then this worked to open a remote shell: `psexec \\192.168.0.3 -u username -p password cmd`. Then  edited the hosts file to add a DNS entry to both machines, can now replace 192.168.0.3 with the specified hostname.

Comment: I get a "no permissions" error even though I'm using the same user/pass that works with Remote Desktop to that machine...

Answer (score 15):

You can use native win command:

```
WMIC /node:ComputerName process call create “cmd.exe /c start.exe”
```

The WMIC is part of wbem win folder: C:\Windows\System32\wbem

Comment: In our network all pcs are in domain , how to execute command with administrator on remote host?

Comment: First try to run the CMD as administartor. If it will not help, try: http://blog.commandlinekungfu.com/2009/05/episode-31-remote-command-execution.html

Comment: "Error: Descripción = El servidor RPC no está disponible."  (RPC server not available)