# Batch: Running files through ssh on Windows machines

Tags: batch-file, ssh

What I'm trying to do might be simple for veteran programmers. I have two Windows machines: MachineA and MachineB. From MachineA, I want to:

1) ssh into MachineB, run a batch file say C:\parent\test.bat -start
2) delete C:\parent folder
3) Copy C:\parent folder from MachineA to the C drive in MachineB
4) Run C:\parent\test.bat -stop
5) I need to do all the above through a script on MachineA (preferably a **Batch Script**)

Most of what I've read so far about this uses plink or other software (someone suggested WinSCP). 
It would be nice if I could do all this WITHOUT installing any software. Any suggestions??
(I do have msysgit on both machines)

Answer (score 0):

SSH is not supported by windows. You will have to install a utility to run a command on a remote machine

You can find details in this post:
[How to execute a dos command on a remote PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935695/how-to-execute-a-dos-command-on-a-remote-pc)

Your other option is to use Windows Powershell scripts.