# Run an executable or a batch file on remote machine

Tags: inno-setup

I have an executable created using Inno Setup. It distributes some files to few remote machines. After copying I would like to run a batch file or executable on a remote machine through Inno Setup.

I tried the following commands but nothing works.

```pascal
ShellExec('', '\\REMOTE_MACHINE\C$\Support\test.exe', '', '', SW_SHOW,
    ewWaitUntilTerminated, ReturnCode);
```

```pascal
Exec('\\REMOTE_MACHINE\C$\Support\test.exe', '', '', SW_SHOW, 
    ewWaitUntilTerminated, ReturnCode);
```

Is there anything I am missing from the above commands? Is there any other function that I can use here?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your options, you can use:

- [PowerShell remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands)
- [PsExec tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)
- WMI

The latter two options are shown in a similar another question:
[How to execute a Windows command on a remote PC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11935695/850848)

An SSH as shown in the answer by @TimSeed is also an option.

---

In your code, you are executing the remote commands locally, not remotely.

Comment: Yes that is what happening in my code. But I want to trigger the executable on remote machine. I am afraid PowerShell and PsExec is not an option for me. As i can't install anything on my client's system. Its Windows XP OS and does not have powershell.

Comment: You do not have to "install" `PsExec`, it a standalone executable. Just embed it to your installer, extract it to a temporary location, run it to execute the command remotely, and delete it.

Comment: WMIC should be available even on Windows XP, but I have no experience with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh - you can run the command remotely

Something like this

```
ssh user@MachineB 'do my commands'
```

If you wish this to happen without typing the password in then you should set up **keyless-ssh**

I am however assuming that this command you wish to run does not require super privileges.

Comment: That is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to this party but this is another option

download plink from putty, then run

`plink -ssh -batch -l user -pw yourpassword remote_ip path_to_bash_script`

plink --help for more info