# Creating a user-mode dump from Kernel debugger

Tags: windbg, crash-dumps

I'm connected to a machine with Kernel Debugger, and hit a stop. How can I use Kernel Debugger to create a *user-mode* dump of a certain process on the machine?

What I tried (edited from comments by @EdChum):

- `.dump` - create a kernel-mode dump
- Use `.shell` to invoke `cdb` or some other tool that creates user-mode dumps - doesn't work, since `.shell` runs on the host (debugger) computer, not the target computer (tested by running `.shell "cmd.exe" -c "/c echo %computername%"`).
- Use remoting tools mentionedd in answers to [a remoting question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11935695) such as `psexec`, `winrs`, `wmic` etc. to invoke cdb etc. - doesn't work, since the target machine stopped with my kernel debugger and can't run any external commands.

Comment: not tried but if you set the current process using `!process` can you then write a mini dump for the current process?

Comment: I think `.dump` produces a kernel-mode mini-dump

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to do this, other than spinning up windbg and then attach to the process of interest and create the mini dump that way, it seems that once it's in kernel debugger mode, you can't switch the mode. You can change the process and thread context to map the virtual address to the process of interest but this doesn't change the debugger mode. You could execute `.shell` and call `cdb` and pass the params to attach to the process and write the dump out but I've never tried this

Comment: @EdChum: I've tested - in live machine-to-machine KD, `.shell` runs on the host (debugger) computer, not the target computer (tested by running `.shell "cmd.exe" -c "/c echo %computername%"`). So that won't work.

Comment: Does any of these answers help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935695/how-to-execute-a-windows-command-on-a-remote-pc?

Comment: @EdChum: No - all the remoting mechanisms (`psexec`, `winrs`, `wmic`) mentioned there depend on the target machine to be running, and not stopped in Kernel Debugger. I'm looking for a way to do it *using the kernel debugger itself*, since it does have access to the entire machine - but I guess it doesn't have this capability...