# Connect to remote machine using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, virtual-machine

I want to connect into a virtual machine (for example has an IP: 192.168.1.2) through ASP.NET and run some commands. Normally, I have to open remote desktop, enter username and password, then run those commands inside the remote machine. Now, I want to reduce my works by calling a function and it will automatically connect to that machine, run those commands and close connection. Does anyone have any ideal? Many many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935695/how-to-execute-a-windows-command-on-a-remote-pc

Comment: @gkulshrestha thank you! I tried and it works. Although `psexec` took about 10sec to make a connection but it's okay for me. Thank you again !!